# Getting count of similar columns (at least 1 column same in the rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1

```
id   name   text
1    apple  hi
2    apple  hello
3    apple  good morning
4    betty  hello
5    betty  good afternoon
```

Hello, let's say I have this table what is the most efficient/simplest sql to get count of similar rows in this case, how many texts for each name such that I get the results combined into 1 table:

```
name   textcount
apple  3
betty  2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select name, count(*) from Table1 group by name
```

you need to read up on "aggregate functions" in SQL. One reference is here: http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlnut/chapter/ch04.html

Comment: Ah, ic. I am so not familiar with the group by function, time to do more read up. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

say i have a similar table as yours:

```
id  name      text
1   apple     hi
2   apple     hello
3   orange    bye
4   orange    how do you do
5   vodafone  good evening
6   orange    good afternoon
```

The simplest query to obtain the count of texts according each name in the table would be:

**QUERY:**

> select name, COUNT (text) as
>   count_text_for_name from table_2 group
>   by name

**Results:**

```
name    count_text_for_name
apple      2
orange    3
vodafone    1
```